# changing colors with jquery with a color picker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, colors

i have this jquery script that changes the color of the background instantly by entering a color code into the textbox, the working example is in jsfiddle link below.

http://jsfiddle.net/7jg4e/

but instead of the input field i wanted to use a color picker custom skin, becuase i dont want user to deal with hex code(just like twitter). the jquery plugin im trying to use is found at

http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/

at the buttom of the page it has the neat color picker with DOM element.

so the problem is how am i going to change from the input type to the color picker div. thanks :))

Comment: try this: http://jsfiddle.net/SpmuV/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace the input element with a div use something like: (untested!)

HTML

```
<div id='colourPicker'></div>
```

JS

```
$('#colourPicker').ColorPicker({
  onChange: function(hsb, hex, rgb){
    $("#full").css("background-color", '#' + hex);
  }
});
```

There's an example at the bottom of the link you have which shows you how.

**Update for changing text**

HTML

```
<div id='colourPickerText'></div>
<div id='textToBeChanged'>Test text</div>
```

JS

```
$('#colourPickerText').ColorPicker({
  onChange: function(hsb, hex, rgb){
    $("#textToBeChanged").css("color", '#' + hex);
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the great answer, but imagine i wanted to chnage the color of the text aswell, how is the div color picker in the html going to differentiate from the two color pickers +upvote from me :))

Comment: Updated answer to show how to change color of text, you could have 2 colour pickers on the form, one for background and one for text.

Comment: can i ask you one more question, sorry, how do i get the value(hex), when the color is sumbited, so i can save it in the database!! im so confused

Comment: Use the onChange event, you will get the hex value there.  See TheVillageIdiots jsFiddle to see how to use the OnChange method.

Answer (score 14):

Just as further reference... `HTML5` already include "color" as an Input type.

```
<label for="bg">Choose color:</label> 
<input id="bg" type="color" />
```

Plus, you can apply some css style with:

```
input[type="color"]{/*css-here*/}
```

Now, for the main question... you can capture the color value to change the bg-color with a simple script.
Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/7jg4e/152/

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
$('#colorSelector').ColorPicker({
onChange: function(hsb, hex, rgb)
          {
            $("#full").css("background-color", hex);
          }
});
```

Comment: what about the html side of things

Comment: Just have a `<div id="colourSelector"></div>` as your colour selector box, and then your `<xxx id="full">` will change whenever it's used.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks keithics..

I had the similar problem. I had to call colorpicker for dynamic buttons. I did with taking `class` instead of `id`.

It helped me a lot.

```
$('.colorSelector').ColorPicker({
onChange: function(hsb, hex, rgb,el)
      {
        $(el).val('#' + hex);
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and below is my solution.

edit colorpicker.js line 96

from

> cal.data('colorpicker').onChange.apply(cal, [col, HSBToHex(col),
>   HSBToRGB(col)]);

to

> cal.data('colorpicker').onChange.apply(cal, [col, HSBToHex(col),
>   HSBToRGB(col), cal.data('colorpicker').el]);

on change event instead of onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) ...

to

> onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb,el) {
>   $(el).val('#' + hex);
>   }

Answer (score 0):

```
let drawingBuffer
      getColor(colorPicker) {
        let color = 'ColorPicker1';
        this.drawingBuffer = document.getElementsByClassName("colorSets");
         for (var i = 0; i < this.drawingBuffer.length; i++) {
             this.drawingBuffer[i].style.color = colorPicker;
         }
         this.drawingBuffer.style.color = colorPicker;
        return color;
    }
<div class="colorSets">test</div>
<div class="colorSets">test1</div>
<input name="MyColorPicker" id="ColorPicker1" [cpPresetLabel]="color" [(colorPicker)]="color" [style.background]="color" (colorPickerChange)="getColor($event)"/>


//this is not working in snipest but use as it code and then use npm install it will work for you
```

Comment: first install use this command to instal angular color picker  
"npm install ngx-color-picker --save"
in above code no need to use "let drawingBuffer"
just use drawingBuffer
this is for angular solution