# How do I create a color legend on my page without a chart?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, legend

I'm using razor on my site which uses ASP.NET Core 7.0. There's a place where I need a color legend, but a google search isn't really turning up what I need. There have been plenty of charts that include color legends, but I just need the legend without the chart. Are there any plugins or libraries like jQuery UI that allow for decent customization and options that I can use to easily build one? If not, what's the recommended approach?

Comment: Do you want [changing colors with jquery with a color picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146621/changing-colors-with-jquery-with-a-color-picker) or [Show legend using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48313985/show-legend-using-jquery) ? Could you explain more ?

Comment: @QingGuo The Show Legend one is exactly what I wanted. I'll need to do a bit of modification, but it will work otherwise. Thank you so much.